# java : `java.util.Map` api for get method

Tags: java, dictionary

I was going though the source code of method `V get(Object key);` of  `java.util.Map` it accepts `Object` as parameter for key, here my question is why it doesn't accept generic type `K` instead of object? So that `get` method will be more type safe?

Answer (score 0):

It has been there before there were generics ... and even before they stated the java version, in which it was added to java, in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).